# play Audio sound with Angular 7 on Android device

Tags: android, cordova, audio, angular7

so i need to play a sound when there is a condition on Angular 7. 
So this is my code:

```
  playAudio() {
    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = '../assets/sound/error-sound.mp3';
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
```

On web all works and the error-sound play.
So but when i build on Android with Apache Cordova, the sound not playing.
I think there's problem about the sound path.

Or like solution i should set the android path and not '..assets/sound/...' ? witch path android using ?

Someone had this problem ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to move the src into the creation of the Audio element like this and then it started playing on my device.

```
let audio = new Audio('assets/sound/error-sound.mp3');
//audio.src = '../assets/sound/error-sound.mp3';
audio.load();
audio.play();
```